# Creating Excel database to track inventory

Tags: database, excel, vba

I will try to explain what I would like to achieve, and since I have not looking for ready-to-go solution, I hope you will give me pointers what to look for.

So, I have one sheet in Excel (Libre, Apache whatever) where I want to keep track of the inventory in offices. I don't have many of them, thus I have opted for something simpler that Access or any other database

So for example in Office 122 I have Dell computer XZY

Now, on next sheet 2 I would like to keep properties of that particular computer (as table for example)

1. Dell computer XZY | CPU Xenon | Nvidia 980 | RAM 16GB
2. Dell computer AAA | CPU I7 | AMD 290X | RAM 32GB

and so on

Now, on the first sheet I have columns

Office | Computer | Specs

I would like to be able set column Computer from drop down selection name of the computer from sheet 2 e.g. Dell computer XZY, and to print out its specs in Info column automatically from the sheet 2 which holds computer names and specs of the computers so it looks something like

Office 122 | Dell Computer AAA (this should be drop down selection) | I7, AMD 290X, 32GB

I hope I was clear enough :). As I said, I don't expect you to make me the sheet (wouldn't mind, but not expecting), just to tell me what I am looking for and where to search since I didn't have any experience with this kind of "databases" in excel.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2011/06/09/restrict-data-entry-in-excel-with-lists.aspx

Comment: I'd look for free Excel inventory or asset tracker templates (with printing capabilities) on that thing they call the Internet. I went to File ► New in Excel and searched for *inventory*. It spit back a few dozen results.

Comment: you may need to reference another sheet: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/15.3

Comment: [Excel is not a database](https://www.google.com/#q=excel+is+not+a+database)

Comment: @Wakizashi if my answer helped you please mark my answer as valid one

Comment: @Parfait you don't say! Read what I have wrote and then explain to me how it is not database and that I should use <insert favorite db here including oracle> to handle my inventory of 50 entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1 make dropdown**

On sheet2 make columns

Restrict your cell to values from a list of items

1. select cell
2. select data validation
3. select allow list
4. select range

Thats it

http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2011/06/09/restrict-data-entry-in-excel-with-lists.aspx

**Part two -lookup value**

With excel formula VLOOPUP you can loopup a value, witch mist be unique and you can select the row which value it should return. Something like this

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,Sheet2!B:C,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: yeah that works I'm aware of that, but I want to print out specs of the selected computer in other field(s)

Comment: Was trying to avoid VLOOKUP, so ended up with something like:

=INDEX($Sheet2.C3:C32;MATCH(B4;$Sheet2.A3:A48;0))

where Validation list is 

$Sheet2.$A$3:$A$48
However VLOOKUP would do the trick as well, thanks